AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'app'
Problems using create_all from mysqllite and flask
I was creating a flask application following a youtube, but when i tried to create a db using
db.create_all()
the following error appeared
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'app'
I used "from roda_teste import app, db", then "with app.app.context():" to use the create_all, my app has the app = Flask(name) line, what`s the issue?
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

#roda o site
app = Flask(__name__)


#adicionando o banco de dados com o sql lite
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.db'

#chave secreta
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "minhaSenhaHiperUltraMegaBlasterSecreta"

#iniciando o banco de dados
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#criando um modelo
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable = False, unique = True)
    #date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)

    #criando uma string
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Name %r>' % self.name

#criando uma classe de formulário, é isso que vou usar no cadastro
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Qual é seu nome", validators=[DataRequired()]) #mostra se você preencheu o formulário
    submit = SubmitField('Enviar')





#rotas das página do site
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def name():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    #validando o form
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
        flash('Enviado com sucesso!')
        
    return render_template('index_teste.html',
        name = name,
        form = form )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)


Did you mean app.app_context instead of app.app.context? Note the underscore (_) replaces the second dot.
